# Public storage - dublicte work

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

I am using Laravel file storage inside my cms system, my issue is the system duplicated every uploaded file inside `/public` and `stroage/app/public`, and in future that will take huge space.
I just want to add everything in `/public` what is the right approach to do that?

Comment: `storage/app/public` should be where everything is stored, `/public` should then just be a `symlink` of `storage/app/public`. Although, that doesn't seem right either...it should be something like `storage/app/public/uploads`, then `/public/uploads` is a symlink of `/storage
/app/public/uploads`

Comment: you need to link storage folder like this [reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/filesystem#the-public-disk)

Comment: Yes i used symlink but now i have uploaded file in two places in storage and public folder, it will take large space in future..